# Should "other than" be followed by the infinitive or the -ing form

Tags: sentence-construction, licensing

> I'd do anything for you to repay my debt, other than killing people.
>
> I'd do anything for you to repay my debt, other than kill people.

Are both sentences grammatically correct?
Is the first more appropriate than the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1.** I'd do anything for you to repay my debt, **other than** *killing people*.
>
> **2.** I'd do anything for you to repay my debt, *other than kill people*.

Both the sentences above are correct. The phrase **other than** here acts in both the sentences like a preposition.

In sentence #1, like other preposition it takes a **Gerund-Participle**.

> I look forward **to** *playing golf* with you.
>
> I feel completely fine **after** *sleeping a full night's sleep*.
>
> I'd do anything for you to repay my debt, **other than** *killing people*.

But sentence #2 is a bit different. The phrase *other than* still works like a preposition there, but the complement it takes in not anything similar to the one a preposition normally licenses. But here the complement it takes is called **Matrix-licensed-complement**. Some other preposition can license similar complements, for example - *except*.

> There is nothing any of us can do **except** *be cautious*. [*We can be cautious*]
>
> I'd do anything for you to repay my debt **other than** *kill people*. [*I can't kill people*]

Comment: Do both the sentences I used as examples mean the same?

Comment: @lekonchekon Yes they do.